# JQuery Success Function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script.  It runs, it passes the variables to the controller, the controller executes correctly, but for whatever reason the success function does not fire and therefore does not refresh my html. Instead the error fires off.  Nothing is jumping out at me as to the cause.  Thanks for the help!

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnUpdateTick").unbind('click').click(function () {
        var currenttick =
            {
                "TicketID":@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.TicketID)),
                "Title": $("#Title").val(),
                "Creator": $("#Creator").val(),
                "StatusID": $("#StatusID").val(),
                "Description": $("#Description").val(),
                "newComment":$("#txtAddComment").val(),
                Cat:
                    {
                        "CatID":$("#ddCurrTickCat").val()
                    }
            }
        //var newcomment = $("#txtAddComment").val();
        var conv = JSON.stringify(currenttick);
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTicket", "HelpDesk")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ticket:currenttick}),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadpartial").html(data);
            },
            error: function (data){alert("turd")}
        });
    });
});
```

My controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult UpdateTicket(Tickets ticket)
    {

        ////Tickets.UpdateTicket(currenttick);

        if (ticket.newComment != "")
        {

            Comments.addCommentToTicket(ticket.TicketID, ticket.newComment,UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName.ToString());
        }
        Tickets model = new Tickets();

        ViewBag.CategoryList = Category.GetCategories();
        ViewBag.StatusList = TicketStatus.GetStatusList();

        model = Tickets.GetTicketByID(ticket.TicketID);
        model.TicketComments = new List<Comments>();
        model.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticket.TicketID);

        //model.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticketID);

        //ViewBag.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticketID);

        return PartialView("TicketDetails", model);
    }
```

Comment: Why not actually look at the error rather than throwing up an alert? What does your controller look like?

Comment: alert("turd"); - HAHA

Comment: Please amend your ajax error handler to this: "function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     alert(thrownError);
                 });" so we get the error message

Comment: (and use a console.log)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I wasn't sure how to get the error to debug it.    IT comes back with Syntax Error: Invalid Character

Comment: Your ajax request seems to be expecting json, however i see no mention of json in your server code, are you sure it is returning json?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is returning a view instead of `json`. You should be returning a `JsonResult` instead. Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateTicket(Tickets ticket)
{

    ////Tickets.UpdateTicket(currenttick);

    if (ticket.newComment != "")
    {

        Comments.addCommentToTicket(ticket.TicketID, ticket.newComment,UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName.ToString());
    }
    Tickets model = new Tickets();

    ViewBag.CategoryList = Category.GetCategories();
    ViewBag.StatusList = TicketStatus.GetStatusList();

    model = Tickets.GetTicketByID(ticket.TicketID);
    model.TicketComments = new List<Comments>();
    model.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticket.TicketID);

    //model.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticketID);

    //ViewBag.TicketComments = Comments.GetCommentsForTicketByID(ticketID);

    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this and my error from Ajax simply states internal server error.  Yet everything is still executing as it should.

Comment: It may require tweaking, I did that from memory and don't have a dev computer to test on right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return Partial view from ajax call then modify ur ajax request as :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateTicket", "HelpDesk")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ticket:currenttick}),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loadpartial").html(data);
        },
        error: function (data){alert("turd")}
    });
```

Now "data" in ur success function will have html returned from PartialViewResult().